# Using code based configuration getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet

Tags: java, spring

Cannot start Spring Web App using only code based configuration. Getting error:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\user1\Idea13 Projects\WebApp\target\WebApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\user1\Idea13 Projects\WebApp\target\WebApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-el-api-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\user1\Idea13 Projects\WebApp\target\WebApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\user1\Idea13 Projects\WebApp\target\WebApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
.........
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/C:/Users/user1/.IntelliJIdea13/system/tomcat/Unnamed_WebApp/conf/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/user1/.IntelliJIdea13/system/tomcat/Unnamed_WebApp/conf/web.xml; lineNumber: 104; columnNumber: 13; Error at (104, 13) : org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Occurred at line 104 column 13
 org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

As I understand it points to `web.xml` but I do not use it. How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

After I removed `catalina*` from deployment path I am getting:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager
```

---

SOLVED

Comment: If question is solved, why don't you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at 
>   file:/C:/Users/user1/.IntelliJIdea13/system/tomcat/Unnamed_WebApp/conf/web.xml
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: 
>   file:/C:/Users/user1/.IntelliJIdea13/system/tomcat/Unnamed_WebApp/conf/web.xml; lineNumber: 
>   104; columnNumber: 13; Error at (104, 13) : org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet

Go to your `WEB-INf/lib` and remove `catalina.*.jar`, then restart your tomcat.
or incase of maven project mention its scope as `provided`

```
 <scope>provided</scope>
```

<sub>Note : The solution is generic , please post your `web.xml` if the issue perists</sub>